# Session returning null even though i can see the values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string UserId { set; get; } 
    public string AccessToken { set; get; }

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unit;

    public BaseController(IUnitOfWork unit)
    {
        _unit = unit;
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
        UserId = Session["_UserId"] as string; 
        AccessToken = Session["_AccessToken"] as string;
        // ......
    }
 }
```

Even though AccessToken returns value. UserId is coming as `null` even though I can debug and see that there is a value in `Session` object.

I m setting them in session:

```
        Session.Add("_UserId", user.Id);
        Session.Add("_AccessToken", user.AccessToken);
```

What s going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UserId = Session["_UserId"] as string;
```

Looks like the value for the key "_UserId" is not a string - hence you get `null` as result.

Comment: :) yeah that s correct. bummer, even if it is an int for id, why it s not casting to string. i was kinda expecting that.